# Why does python "import platform" module cause duplicated/repeated prints?

Tags: python, module, platform

**Background:**

- I'm working on a Macbook Pro / High Sierra 10.13.3
- Python version: 2.7.10

**WORKS FINE:** I have a simple test file called "test.py" that contains only the following two lines.

```
print '------- START -------'
print '------- END ---------'
```

I execute the file with the command "python test.py" and, as expected, it correct prints:

```
------- START -------
------- END ---------
```

**FAILURE SCENARIO:** However, if I add the "import platform" statement, so that the file contains:

```
import platform

print '------- START -------'
print '------- END ---------'
```

When I execute it the exact same way, I get duplicated/repeated prints to stdout, as follows:

```
------- START -------
------- END ---------
------- START -------
------- END ---------
```

**MY QUESTION:** Why does including the platform module via the "import platform" statement cause duplicate/repeated prints to stdout?

NOTE: I tried importing other modules like "OS" and it doesn't happen.

Comment: Never heard this... Add a screenshot?

Comment: Python 2.7 comes with a standard module `test`. That module may be implicitly imported by `platform` or one of the modules that `platform` imports. Rename `test.py` to something else, remove `test.pyc`, and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks but it makes no difference. I just tried with many different file names and always the same result.  (I also removed the *.pyc files before and after every run for every file rename.)

Comment: Tried, only **one** output. Have you a file `platform.py` in the ame directory as `test.py`?

Comment: That's it!  For some reason, if you import the platform module into a totally different script (let's call it "abc.py"), when you also have a script called "platform.py" in the directory, executing "abc.py" will first execute the "platform.py" script before the contents of "abc.py" are executed. "Why" do you believe this happens?